# shell to find the xml tags for a given attribute

Tags: xml, shell

Need help in finding a simple shell function to get below input :
1.XML file
2.a pattern

output will be the section of the XML file from the open tag till the closing tag where this pattern is inside (tags names are known)

example
XML file section

```
<dependency>
<artifact>AAA</artifact>
<package>BBB</package>
<version>${versionParam}</version>
</dependency>
```

pattern to check is "BBB"

the output should be the whole section above out of the XML file (i.e. from dependency open tag to dependency closing tag)

note - It is known/assumed that the pattern needs to be inside a "dependency" tag

What I have so far is a function which will go over all the XML find all the dependency tags and then search for this pattern inside each dependency

the function works but it is not efficient enough
I am looking for something which will not scan all XML and all dependencies tags in them but somehow will find it faster :-)
my code has huge amount of XMLs with huge amount of dependency tags - this is the reason i am looking for something faster

thanks in advance

Comment: The best language to query XML is XQuery. I am not sure if it is applicable for your environments.

Comment: It is not clear how you expect code to avoid to read through the whole XML document if you are looking for all `dependency` elements having that `package` value (e.g. `BBB`). If you are only interested in the first match then XSLT 3 with streaming and e.g. `xsl:iterate` and `xsl:break` can stop processing in Saxon EE after finding the first match. The other option is to use an XML database, once you have inserted and indexed the file a search should be faster than code reading through.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a comment, XQuery is the way to go to find and extract data from XML files in shell scripts.

Using `xmllint`, a commonly-installed command line utility for working with XML:

```sh
 xmllint --xpath '//dependency[contains(., "BBB")]' input.xml
```

Or `xmlstarlet`, another useful XML tool:

```sh
xmlstarlet sel -t -c '//dependency[contains(., "BBB")]' input.xml
```

Comment: Many thanks ! 
was not familiar with these utilities - excellent!

Comment: Or with `xidel`: `xidel -s input.xml -e '//dependency[contains(., "BBB")]' --printed-node-format=xml`, `xidel -s input.xml -e '//dependency[contains(., "BBB")]/outer-xml()'`.